# How to enable 'Double Tab to unlock' feature in android

Tags: android

In android phone app, I use touch screen to dial a number. And then I place the phone next to my ear for the phone call. And android will show 'Double Tab to unlock' on screen to disable anything activated/touched.

Can you please tell me how can I do that in my own application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer and if there has been no activity for a certain period of time throw a view up over your UI and have it listen for a double tap.  Once it registers a double tap have it go away.

Comment: but how can i swallow (i.e. not doing anything) for all other events?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

It says "Returns True if the event was handled, false otherwise."  So just override this and return true so the events don't propagate to any other views.